# C #define causes Seg Fault?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

Here is the function I am trying to get to working on Red Hat 6..

And I have very little experience with C, and especially using #define, so I'm unsure what this portion is even trying to do: **SP->s_port = htons(SP->s_port);**

```
#ifdef __linux
#define GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME(SP, SERVICE, PROTOCOL)                           \
   char            GSBN_servbuf[HOSTBUFFERLENGTH] = {0};                     \
   struct servent  GSBN_sp;                                                  \
   struct servent *GSBN_serv_result;                                         \
   int             GSBN_s = 0;                                               \
   GSBN_s = getservbyname_r(SERVICE,                                         \
                       PROTOCOL,                                             \
                       &GSBN_sp,                                             \
                       GSBN_servbuf,                                         \
                       sizeof(GSBN_servbuf),                                 \
                       &GSBN_serv_result);                                   \
   SP = GSBN_serv_result;                                                    \
   SP->s_port = htons(SP->s_port);                                           \
   if (SP && SOCKET_DEBUG) {                                                 \
      printf("%s GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME - Service: %s Port: %d Protocol: %s\n", \
             get_timestamp(), SP->s_name, SP->s_port, SP->s_proto);          \
       }                                                                         \
   if (SP == NULL) {                                                         \
      fprintf(stderr, "%s GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME - Service %s not found.\n",    \
              get_timestamp(), SERVICE);                                     \
   }
#else
#define GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME(SP, SERVICE, PROTOCOL)                           \
   char            GSBN_servbuf[HOSTBUFFERLENGTH] = {0};                     \
   struct servent  GSBN_serv_result;                                         \
   SP = getservbyname_r(SERVICE,                                             \
                       PROTOCOL,                                             \
                       &GSBN_serv_result,                                    \
                       GSBN_servbuf,                                         \
                       sizeof(GSBN_servbuf));                                \
   if (SP && SOCKET_DEBUG) {                                                 \
      printf("%s GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME - Service: %s Port: %d Protocol: %s\n", \
             get_timestamp(), SP->s_name, SP->s_port, SP->s_proto);          \
   }                                                                         \
   if (SP == NULL) {                                                         \
      fprintf(stderr, "%s GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME - Service %s not found.\n",    \
              get_timestamp(), SERVICE);                                     \
   }
#endif
```

This is the error I am getting:

According to gdb I am getting a seg fault at this function call:

**GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME(sp, serv, prot);**

Here is the gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x456c6c90 (LWP 14645)]
0x420b1e69 in gi_get_port (serv=Unhandled dwarf expression opcode 0x9c
)
    at /home/user1/Common/src/socket.c:282
282           GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME(sp, serv, prot);
Current language:  auto; currently c
```

Here is how the function is called:

```
int gi_get_port (char *serv, char *prot)
/* obtain the port for the named service */
{
  int p, s;

  /* Data for resolving service name to a socket description. */
  struct servent *sp = NULL;

  GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME(sp, serv, prot);

  if (sp != NULL) {
    p = sp->s_port;
  } else {
    p = -1;
  };

  return p;
}
```

Comment: htons = "Host TO Network Short": convert a short integer from host byte order (LSB on Intel) into network byte order (MSB) for the servent structure.

Comment: I think sp is a struct servent*, as it is declared as   
  struct servent *sp = NULL;

Comment: Actually is GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME a macro or a function? I'd read it as a macro, but if it's a function then jleedev's right, you need to specify the argument types in the declaration and the value assigned to SP in it won't get leaked out. Is that really exactly what you've got?

Comment: @Rup: It's has to be a macro - it doesn't use valid function syntax

Comment: @Ken Yeah, but if it was a macro it'd need lots of backslash line continuations, plus the #define obviously. So as it stands it's neither.

Comment: Just wait.. you guys are right... Update coming... (I though I could just turn a #define into a function because I was seeing a seg fault)

Comment: Why are these macros and not functions? :|

Comment: I wish I knew... I didn't write this code.. I'm just trying to get this to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your code will look like once the preprocessor is executed :

```
int gi_get_port (char *serv, char *prot)
/* obtain the port for the named service */
{
  int p, s;

  /* Data for resolving service name to a socket description. */
  struct servent *sp = NULL;

  char            GSBN_servbuf[HOSTBUFFERLENGTH] = {0};                     
   struct servent  GSBN_sp;                                                  
   struct servent *GSBN_serv_result;                                         
   int             GSBN_s = 0;                                               
   GSBN_s = getservbyname_r(serv,                                         
                       prot,                                             
                       &GSBN_sp,                                             
                       GSBN_servbuf,                                         
                       sizeof(GSBN_servbuf),                                 
                       &GSBN_serv_result);                                   
   sp = GSBN_serv_result;                                                    
   sp->s_port = htons(SP->s_port);                                           
   if (sp && SOCKET_DEBUG) {                                                 
      printf("%s GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME - Service: %s Port: %d Protocol: %s\n", 
             get_timestamp(), sp->s_name, sp->s_port, sp->s_proto);          
       }                                                                         
   if (sp == NULL) {                                                         
      fprintf(stderr, "%s GET_SERVICE_BY_NAME - Service %s not found.\n",    
              get_timestamp(), serv);                                     
   }

  if (sp != NULL) {
    p = sp->s_port;
  } else {
    p = -1;
  };

  return p;
}
```

As you see, you should be checking for 'sp' being 'NULL' before you do the htons() on the port.

Answer (score 0):

How long is your HOSTBUFFERLENGTH ?

Compiling and running the code, I can generate a similar crash if HOSTBUFFERLENGTH is set to one, but it looks like it works if it is set to 2000....

AND if the service name name is invalid (e.g "akhaha" instead of say "http", then GSBN_serv_result is NULL and the SP is NULL, and the SP->s_port will cause the crash as well.....

Comment: Here is what hostbufferlength is set to

#define HOSTBUFFERLENGTH 1024

Comment: The problem is with the SP being a NULL pointer for invalid service names... You need to check for NULL.